# Create a tuple using interrelated lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists which are interlinked as example

```
name=['pablo','rob','rahul','roni']
```

and

```
age=[21,23,20,24]
```

I have to create a tuple using these 2 lists.

Final output should be
    data={'pablo':21,'rob':23,'rahul':20,'roni':24}.

And let the output of the above problem is given. How can I get back the original lists i.e. 'name' and 'age'.

How can I do it using python commands?

Comment: Aside: you say "tuple", but it looks like you want a dictionary instead.

Comment: What is the difference between tuple and dictionary in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up your lists; pass that straight to `dict()` to produce your dictionary:

```
data = dict(zip(name, age))
```

`zip()` produces an iterator that gives you tuples with each element from each input paired up. `dict()` is quite happy to take those pairs and interpret those as key-value pairs.

Demo:

```
>>> name=['pablo','rob','rahul','roni']
>>> age=[21,23,20,24]
>>> zip(name, age)
<zip object at 0x10a6d0e08>
>>> list(zip(name, age))
[('pablo', 21), ('rob', 23), ('rahul', 20), ('roni', 24)]
>>> dict(zip(name, age))
{'roni': 24, 'pablo': 21, 'rahul': 20, 'rob': 23}
```

Take into account that dictionary ordering is arbitrary, so the `list()` and `dict()` pair orders are different.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> name = ['pablo','rob','rahul','roni']
>>> age = [21,23,20,24]
>>> {n: a for n, a in zip(name, age)}
{'pablo': 21, 'rahul': 20, 'rob': 23, 'roni': 24}
```